# Plot vectors of different size in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Let's assume I have `t`vector= `1:15` and I have two other vectors : `X` of size 15, each element of `X` relates to the corresponding element (element of same index) in `t` ; and `Y` of size 5, each element of `Y` corresponds to `t=3,6,9,12,15`.

How can I plot `X`and `Y` on the same plot w.r.t. `t`, though `X` and `Y` does not have the same length (especially `Y` is not of same length as `t`)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an example of what you are trying to achieve, in code, we have to guess at your exact intentions.

However, one option could be to plot a sub-selection of `t` against `Y`, something like this (using the values from your example):

```
plot(t, X, t(3:3:15), Y)
```

Of course this assumes that your values are actually spaced like your example.

Another option could be to use `NaN` values as placeholders in the `Y` vector, to make it the same length as `t`. You may have to use markers (e.g. `'o'`) in that case.

The best approach really depends on the context.